# Having trouble installing DateTime on OSX Mojave

Tags: perl, datetime, macos-mojave, cpanm

All my perl codes were working fine in the past. I got a new Mac which came with Mojave OSX Ver10.14.1. Got excited and ported in all my old stuff. Now all the scripts are failing and I am not able to install any new modules via cpan. So, after some of research, I opted out for perlbrew.

I have installed "brew install perl" and and now on perl v5.28.1.

When I run my script, it fails as so.

`Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DateTime module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1) at sch_update.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sch_update.pl line 6.`

That should be easy and just install the module. So, I proceeded. Ended up with following error message.

`> sudo cpanm DateTime
--> Working on DateTime
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-1.50.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DateTime-1.50 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: DateTime::Locale, DateTime::TimeZone, namespace::autoclean
--> Working on DateTime::Locale
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-Locale-1.23.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DateTime-Locale-1.23 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: namespace::autoclean
--> Working on namespace::autoclean
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/namespace-autoclean-0.28.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring namespace-autoclean-0.28 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: B::Hooks::EndOfScope, namespace::clean
--> Working on B::Hooks::EndOfScope
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Variable::Magic
--> Working on Variable::Magic
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/V/VP/VPIT/Variable-Magic-0.62.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Variable-Magic-0.62 ... OK
Building and testing Variable-Magic-0.62 ... FAIL
! Installing Variable::Magic failed. See /Users/bpark1/.cpanm/work/1547585021.44629/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Variable::Magic' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24.
--> Working on namespace::clean
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RI/RIBASUSHI/namespace-clean-0.27.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring namespace-clean-0.27 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Package::Stash, B::Hooks::EndOfScope
--> Working on Package::Stash
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Package-Stash-0.38.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Package-Stash-0.38 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Package::Stash::XS
--> Working on Package::Stash::XS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Package-Stash-XS-0.29.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Package-Stash-XS-0.29 ... OK
Building and testing Package-Stash-XS-0.29 ... FAIL
! Installing Package::Stash::XS failed. See /Users/bpark1/.cpanm/work/1547585021.44629/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Package::Stash::XS' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Package-Stash-0.38.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'B::Hooks::EndOfScope' is not installed, Module 'Package::Stash' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for namespace-clean-0.27.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'namespace::clean' is not installed, Module 'B::Hooks::EndOfScope' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for namespace-autoclean-0.28.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'namespace::autoclean' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for DateTime-Locale-1.23.
--> Working on DateTime::TimeZone
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-TimeZone-2.23.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DateTime-TimeZone-2.23 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: namespace::autoclean
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'namespace::autoclean' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for DateTime-TimeZone-2.23.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'DateTime::TimeZone' is not installed, Module 'namespace::autoclean' is not installed, Module 'DateTime::Locale' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for DateTime-1.50.`

I tried using '--installdeps' in cpanm to see if the dependancies would be taken care, but not work.

Please help.

Adding build.log

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.9018 on perl 5.028001 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
Work directory is /Users/bpark1/.cpanm/work/1547585021.44629
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/curl: curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.4 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching DateTime () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DateTime
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-1.50.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DateTime-1.50.tar.gz
Entering DateTime-1.50
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring DateTime-1.50
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite DateTime::Locale 1.06 not found.
Warning: prerequisite DateTime::TimeZone 2.02 not found.
Warning: prerequisite namespace::autoclean 0.19 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DateTime
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Specio 0.18 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have utf8 0 ... Yes (1.21)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Test::Warnings 0.005 ... Yes (0.026)
Checking if you have DateTime::Locale 1.06 ... No
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.96 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have Specio::Library::Builtins 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Specio::Library::String 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Specio::Declare 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Try::Tiny 0 ... Yes (0.30)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Check 0.011 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have integer 0 ... Yes (1.01)
Checking if you have DateTime::TimeZone 2.02 ... No
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.30)
Checking if you have namespace::autoclean 0.19 ... No
Checking if you have warnings::register 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Requirements 0 ... Yes (2.140)
Checking if you have Specio::Exporter 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Params::ValidationCompiler 0.26 ... Yes (0.30)
Checking if you have overload 0 ... Yes (1.30)
Checking if you have Specio::Library::Numeric 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have POSIX 0 ... Yes (1.84)
Checking if you have Storable 0 ... Yes (3.08)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have parent 0 ... Yes (0.236)
==> Found dependencies: DateTime::Locale, DateTime::TimeZone, namespace::autoclean
Searching DateTime::Locale (1.06) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DateTime::Locale
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-Locale-1.23.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DateTime-Locale-1.23.tar.gz
Entering DateTime-Locale-1.23
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::ShareDir::Install 0.03 ... Yes (0.13)
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Configuring DateTime-Locale-1.23
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite namespace::autoclean 0.19 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DateTime::Locale
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Storable 0 ... Yes (3.08)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have File::ShareDir 0 ... Yes (1.116)
Checking if you have Params::ValidationCompiler 0.13 ... Yes (0.30)
Checking if you have Exporter 0 ... Yes (5.73)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0 ... Yes (0.2304)
Checking if you have namespace::autoclean 0.19 ... No
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Requirements 0 ... Yes (2.140)
Checking if you have IPC::System::Simple 0 ... Yes (1.25)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Check 0.011 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.96 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have Specio::Library::String 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Specio::Declare 0 ... Yes (0.43)
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have Test::File::ShareDir::Dist 0 ... Yes (1.001002)
Checking if you have utf8 0 ... Yes (1.21)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Test::Warnings 0 ... Yes (0.026)
Checking if you have List::Util 1.45 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
==> Found dependencies: namespace::autoclean
Searching namespace::autoclean (0.19) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on namespace::autoclean
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/namespace-autoclean-0.28.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking namespace-autoclean-0.28.tar.gz
Entering namespace-autoclean-0.28
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring namespace-autoclean-0.28
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite B::Hooks::EndOfScope 0.12 not found.
Warning: prerequisite namespace::clean 0.20 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for namespace::autoclean
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have B::Hooks::EndOfScope 0.12 ... No
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have FindBin 0 ... Yes (1.51)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have overload 0 ... Yes (1.30)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have List::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Sub::Identify 0 ... Yes (0.14)
Checking if you have namespace::clean 0.20 ... No
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.85)
Checking if you have constant 0 ... Yes (1.33)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
==> Found dependencies: B::Hooks::EndOfScope, namespace::clean
Searching B::Hooks::EndOfScope (0.12) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on B::Hooks::EndOfScope
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24.tar.gz
Entering B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Text::ParseWords 0 ... Yes (3.30)
Configuring B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24
Running Makefile.PL
Distribution opts in x_use_unsafe_inc: 0
In file included from HASCOMPILERel7O/TESTQjCr.c:3:
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:719:13: warning: non-portable path to file '<Xlocale.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#   include <xlocale.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
            <Xlocale.h>
1 warning generated.
Warning: prerequisite Variable::Magic 0.48 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for B::Hooks::EndOfScope
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Module::Implementation 0.05 ... Yes (0.09)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have IPC::Open2 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Checking if you have File::Glob 0 ... Yes (1.31)
Checking if you have Tie::Hash 0 ... Yes (1.05)
Checking if you have Hash::Util::FieldHash 0 ... Yes (1.20)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have lib 0 ... Yes (0.64)
Checking if you have Sub::Exporter::Progressive 0.001006 ... Yes (0.001013)
Checking if you have Variable::Magic 0.48 ... No
==> Found dependencies: Variable::Magic
Searching Variable::Magic (0.48) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Variable::Magic
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/V/VP/VPIT/Variable-Magic-0.62.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Variable-Magic-0.62.tar.gz
Entering Variable-Magic-0.62
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Config 0 ... Yes (5.028001)
Configuring Variable-Magic-0.62
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if this is ActiveState Perl 5.8.8 build 822 or higher... no
Checking if this is gcc 3.4 on Windows trying to link against an import library... no
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Variable::Magic
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have Socket 0 ... Yes (2.027)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have POSIX 0 ... Yes (1.84)
Checking if you have Exporter 0 ... Yes (5.73)
Checking if you have IO::Handle 0 ... Yes (1.39)
Checking if you have Config 0 ... Yes (5.028001)
Checking if you have IPC::Open3 0 ... Yes (1.20)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have lib 0 ... Yes (0.64)
Checking if you have IO::Select 0 ... Yes (1.39)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.30)
Building and testing Variable-Magic-0.62
cp lib/Variable/Magic.pm blib/lib/Variable/Magic.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Magic ()
chmod 644 "Magic.bs"
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Magic.bs blib/arch/auto/Variable/Magic/Magic.bs 644
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/typemap'  Magic.xs > Magic.xsc
mv Magic.xsc Magic.c
cc -c   -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"0.62\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.62\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   Magic.c
In file included from Magic.xs:10:
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:719:13: warning: non-portable path to file '<Xlocale.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#   include <xlocale.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
            <Xlocale.h>
Magic.xs:1297:12: warning: initializing 'const U8 *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') with an expression of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
 const U8 *s = VOID2(const U8 *, VOID2(const void *, SvPV_const(sv, len)));
           ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Variable/Magic/Magic.bundle
cc  -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong  Magic.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Variable/Magic/Magic.bundle  \
          \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Variable/Magic/Magic.bundle
Manifying 1 pod document
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Magic.bs blib/arch/auto/Variable/Magic/Magic.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# Testing Variable::Magic 0.62, Perl 5.028001 (no patchlevel), /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl
t/00-load.t .......... ok
t/01-import.t ........ ok
t/02-constants.t ..... ok
# Using threads 2.22
# Using threads::shared 1.58
t/09-load-threads.t .. 
All 2 subtests passed 
t/10-simple.t ........ ok
t/11-multiple.t ...... 
Failed 59/74 subtests 
t/13-data.t .......... 
Failed 32/35 subtests 
t/14-callbacks.t ..... 
Failed 21/26 subtests 
# According to Config::Perl::V version 0.29, this is NOT a debugging perl
# Not testing global destruction
t/15-self.t .......... 
Failed 159/162 subtests 
# Using Hash::Util::FieldHash 1.20
t/16-huf.t ........... 
Failed 11/18 subtests 
# Using IO::Handle 1.39
# Using IO::Select 1.39
# Using IPC::Open3 1.20
t/17-ctl.t ........... 
Failed 96/96 subtests 
t/18-opinfo.t ........ 
Failed 138/139 subtests 
t/20-get.t ........... 
Failed 11/15 subtests 
t/21-set.t ........... 
Failed 14/18 subtests 
t/22-len.t ........... 
Failed 53/55 subtests 
t/23-clear.t ......... 
Failed 14/18 subtests 
t/24-free.t .......... 
Failed 7/11 subtests 
# Using Tie::Array 1.07
t/25-copy.t .......... 
Failed 43/48 subtests 
t/27-local.t ......... 
Failed 19/24 subtests 
t/28-uvar.t .......... 
Failed 70/75 subtests 
t/30-scalar.t ........ 
Failed 72/76 subtests 
t/31-array.t ......... 
Failed 61/68 subtests 
t/32-hash.t .......... 
Failed 90/94 subtests 
t/33-code.t .......... 
Failed 25/36 subtests 
# Using Symbol 1.08
t/34-glob.t .......... 
Failed 31/35 subtests 
t/35-stash.t ......... 
Failed 43/43 subtests 
# Using threads 2.22
# Using threads::shared 1.58
t/40-threads.t ....... 
All 3 subtests passed 
# Using threads 2.22
# Using threads::shared 1.58
t/41-clone.t ......... 
All 6 subtests passed 
t/50-return.t ........ 
Failed 33/33 subtests 
t/80-leaks.t ......... 
Failed 47/47 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/09-load-threads.t (Wstat: 11 Tests: 2 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/11-multiple.t    (Wstat: 11 Tests: 15 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 74 tests but ran 15.
t/13-data.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 35 tests but ran 3.
t/14-callbacks.t   (Wstat: 11 Tests: 5 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 26 tests but ran 5.
t/15-self.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 162 tests but ran 3.
t/16-huf.t         (Wstat: 11 Tests: 7 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 18 tests but ran 7.
t/17-ctl.t         (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 96 tests but ran 0.
t/18-opinfo.t      (Wstat: 11 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 139 tests but ran 1.
t/20-get.t         (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 15 tests but ran 4.
t/21-set.t         (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 18 tests but ran 4.
t/22-len.t         (Wstat: 11 Tests: 2 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 55 tests but ran 2.
t/23-clear.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 18 tests but ran 4.
t/24-free.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 11 tests but ran 4.
t/25-copy.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 5 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 48 tests but ran 5.
t/27-local.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 5 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 24 tests but ran 5.
t/28-uvar.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 5 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 75 tests but ran 5.
t/30-scalar.t      (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 76 tests but ran 4.
t/31-array.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 7 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 68 tests but ran 7.
t/32-hash.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 94 tests but ran 4.
t/33-code.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 11 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 36 tests but ran 11.
t/34-glob.t        (Wstat: 11 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 35 tests but ran 4.
t/35-stash.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 43 tests but ran 0.
t/40-threads.t     (Wstat: 11 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/41-clone.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 6 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/50-return.t      (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 33 tests but ran 0.
t/80-leaks.t       (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 47 tests but ran 0.
Files=30, Tests=198,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.05 sys +  1.42 cusr  0.23 csys =  1.77 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 26/30 test programs. 0/198 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing Variable::Magic failed. See /Users/bpark1/.cpanm/work/1547585021.44629/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Variable::Magic' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.24.
Searching namespace::clean (0.20) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on namespace::clean
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RI/RIBASUSHI/namespace-clean-0.27.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking namespace-clean-0.27.tar.gz
Entering namespace-clean-0.27
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring namespace-clean-0.27
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite B::Hooks::EndOfScope 0.12 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Package::Stash 0.23 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for namespace::clean
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Package::Stash 0.23 ... No
Checking if you have B::Hooks::EndOfScope 0.12 ... No
Checking if you have Test::More 0.47 ... Yes (1.302156)
==> Found dependencies: Package::Stash, B::Hooks::EndOfScope
Searching Package::Stash (0.23) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Package::Stash
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Package-Stash-0.38.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Package-Stash-0.38.tar.gz
Entering Package-Stash-0.38
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Text::ParseWords 0 ... Yes (3.30)
Checking if you have Config 0 ... Yes (5.028001)
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Configuring Package-Stash-0.38
Running Makefile.PL
Distribution opts in x_use_unsafe_inc: 0
Warning: prerequisite Package::Stash::XS 0.26 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Package::Stash
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have IPC::Open3 0 ... Yes (1.20)
Checking if you have IO::Handle 0 ... Yes (1.39)
Checking if you have B 0 ... Yes (1.74)
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have Symbol 0 ... Yes (1.08)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have Module::Implementation 0.06 ... Yes (0.09)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Package::Stash::XS 0.26 ... No
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have constant 0 ... Yes (1.33)
Checking if you have Getopt::Long 0 ... Yes (2.5)
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have lib 0 ... Yes (0.64)
==> Found dependencies: Package::Stash::XS
Searching Package::Stash::XS (0.26) on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Package::Stash::XS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Package-Stash-XS-0.29.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Package-Stash-XS-0.29.tar.gz
Entering Package-Stash-XS-0.29
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring Package-Stash-XS-0.29
Running Makefile.PL
Distribution opts in x_use_unsafe_inc: 0
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Package::Stash::XS
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have lib 0 ... Yes (0.64)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.50)
Checking if you have constant 0 ... Yes (1.33)
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.30)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.42)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.014)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.74)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.27)
Checking if you have Symbol 0 ... Yes (1.08)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (1.302156)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.11)
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have B 0 ... Yes (1.74)
Checking if you have IO::Handle 0 ... Yes (1.39)
Checking if you have IPC::Open3 0 ... Yes (1.20)
Building and testing Package-Stash-XS-0.29
Distribution opts in x_use_unsafe_inc: 0
```

Comment: Two things - you should not need sudo to install to your perlbrew perl (in fact that may confuse it, since perlbrew depends on your environment), and the failure is in the installation of Variable::Magic, you need to check the log it mentions for details.

Comment: What is in `/Users/bpark1/.cpanm/work/1547585021.44629/build.log`?

Comment: Since it was Variable::Magic and Package::Stash::XS that failed, my guess is that you do not have a complete C compiler/build toolchain setup.

Comment: I did tried cpanm without "sudo", but still same error appeared.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful feedbacks Grinnz/mob! Please help me with toolchain setup check. I'm new to this and not sure how to check.. :-(  Also, I'll update the main thread with the build.log info.

Comment: Apologies... Apparently, I don't know how to post a file nor put a large log info here... I'm new to StackOverflow and any guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Paste it into your question, select the text, and do CTRL+K to indent it so it appears as a code block.

Comment: Added what I could fit. There is 30k char limit that I couldn't include last 1/3rd the log. Hope this is enough.

Comment: Hi @Brian, I see you wrote "opted out for perlbrew" ... and indeed it looks like you try to install a more or less new 'system' perl, using `brew`. @Grinnz is correct, iff using perlbrew, than `sudo cpanm` would not be needed. @Brian, unless you have specific reasons you do not want to use perlbrew, I would suggest to start all over again (even reinstall Mojave to get rid off artefacts from previous attempts). Perlbrew makes playing with perl and even running large scale webservers just a breeze. Also, look at `https://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html` after installing from `perlbrew.pl`

Comment: I misread the question earlier, am I understanding correctly that this is a homebrew perl not perlbrew, and that's why it's in `/usr/local/Cellar`? These are different tools.

Comment: @vanHoesel, thanks for the pointer, but this is work laptop and reinstalling the OS and starting from scratch is challenging. Hoping to see if we can resolve this.

Comment: @Grinnz, I installed via "brew perl". Frankly, I lost track of perlbrew vs brew vs homebrew... Let me know if there is anything I can try in this front. Or is there a way to "uninstall" the tool to see if I can try it again without having to reinstall OSX Mojave?

Comment: @Brian, no worries, if you can, start all over again – without wiping the Mac – , following the instructions on perlbrew.pl. Most likely, the perl installed by homebrew can safely be removed.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian, no worries, if you can, start all over again, following the instructions on perlbrew.pl. Most likely, the perl installed by homebrew can safely be removed.